# How long is it going to take to reach thermal equilibrium between two bodies (mug cooling device)

Tags: thermodynamics

I want to build the following device, but I'd like to understand the physics behind it so that I can optimize the surface area and volume of the pipe. The device in its cross section looks as follows:

[image]

Basically this is a copper spiral filled with frozen water which you can submerge in a mug in order to cool the liquid down. There are already some reusable metal (filled with liquid?) "ice cubes" you can buy, but I find them annoying to handle and remove from the mug after their job is done.

Let's assume the following data:
beverage volume: 250ml 
beverage temperature: 21*C
ice temperature: -10*C

outer surface area of the pipe: 0.024m^2, 
outer diameter of the pipe: 6mm, 
inner diameter of the pipe: 4mm, 
inner surface area of the pipe: 0.016m^2 
outer (copper) volume of the pipe: 2e-5m^3
inner (water ice) volume of the pipe: 1.6e-5m^3

I want to learn how long it is going to take to reach thermal equilibrium between the water inside the pipe and the fluid in the mug and what is going to be the final temperature of both liquids. How do I approach this problem?

I guess this is not trivial because phenomena like heat transfer, diffusion and convection come into play and it will be definitely cooling down faster if I keep moving the spiral along the mug. I'm also well aware that the volume of water filling the pipe is quite tiny and it won't cool it down much, but primarily I want to understand how to model the problem so that I can run some optimizations

Comment: Copper has a [very high](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/thrcn.html) [thermal conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity), but it could be somewhat toxic.

Comment: I agree, however it's possible to have it galvanically plated so that it won't be toxic anymore in contact with liquid. The plating thickness would most lilkely have a negligible impact on the accuracy of the model

Comment: perhaps do away with the ice and use a solid metal coil, maybe stainless steel for non toxicity

Comment: You need some software like COMSOL to solve the thermodynamics + fluid dynamics, as this is a complicated coupled problem

Comment: I am sure this problem is possible to solve in an approximate manner without any software. Such problems have been solved back in XIX century for steam engines and they didn't have computers. I just lack the knowledge to approach it

Comment: I think you should define your objectives like how much you want to cool the beverage and how long you want to wait because they may compete with each other. E.g. increasing the surface to volume ratio increases the heat transfer rate but could lower the heat capacity. If you only want moderate cooling but quickly then maybe solid stainless steel may be the way to go per Adrian’ suggestion

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask this question on the Engineering stack. I suspect that with repeated heating & cooling the galvanizing may flake off the copper. And if you're using it to cool acidic drinks, they could dissolve some zinc. Although zinc has low toxicity in humans, it's not totally harmless, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_toxicity

Comment: Use a heat pipe, much more practical and very efficient.

Comment: Water expands when it freezes.  This will put stress on your copper coil and may cause it to split.  In addition, any plating that you use will get stretched, and probably crack, which will once again expose you to copper in your drink.

Comment: @MaxWalczak If you want a simple approximation, just use [Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_law_of_cooling). Also, if you want to reply to a person, use `@handle` notation

Comment: @KyleKanos that's exactly what I needed, thank you! If you could elaborate some more on a solution with this, I'd be extremely thankful

Comment: @MaxWalczak there are solutions on the Wikipedia entry, just under the heading *Temperature function-of-time solution in terms of object heat capacity*

Comment: Regarding implementation: Would it be an option to make the cup a sophisticated thing where you would change the cup's genus and make the spiral from ceramic (same as the cup) and have a liquid in- and outlet, or from gold (probably too expensive). Ceramics can be a reasonable heat conductor due to the phononic contribution. Then the cup's in/outlet could be attached "on demand" to a little machine with a pump that keeps a thermally insulated cold water reservoir close to 0°C in the summer when connected to mains. Then you can cool your drink down in seconds, and no ice cubes involved!

Comment: @GeorgE. that's too expensive and impractical. I'm capable of manufacturing a self-cooling mug with a spiral in the walls, but the chiller unit would have to be quite large and loud to cool down my drink and then I'd have to be able to unplug it from the unit